# Proper usage of cucumber with typescript?

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I was following a [tutorial](https://sylvain.pontoreau.com/2018/04/30/typescript-cucumber-getting-started/) but the setup is really bad. Basically it uses typescript to convert .ts files to .js. So basically pollutes your whole source code with .js files around.

So as soon as you import your .ts file from source code, all dependencies are duplicated with a .js file.

Do you know how to do proper typescript cucumber tests?

A hacky solution: Copy all features and all files to another temp folder, run from there. I would expect cucumber to be a bit more mature than this, hence my question here?

Or change the configuration of cucumber to look in the build folder from ts.

Thank you

## Why just using typescript won't work:

Code structure:

- tests

  - a.feature
  - stepDefinitions.ts

Now you will compile the typescript and have this structure:

- tests

  - a.feature
  - stepDefinitions.ts
- build

  - tests

    - stepDefinitions.js

Now you can see that `stepDefinitions.js` has no idea where to find `a.feature`. If you run cucumber on the build/test folder it won't find any step feature to run... because well, they are in the tests folder. So the hacky way to fix it is to copy over the features files resulting this structure:

- tests

  - a.feature
  - stepDefinitions.ts
- build

  - tests

    - a.feature
    - stepDefinitions.js

Now it will work but is hacky, I don't like it.

Comment: The [cucumberjs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) project has pretty good documentation on GitHub that might help you. Otherwise you can join the [Cucumber slack](https://cucumberbdd-slack-invite.herokuapp.com/) to get some specific help from the community.

Comment: @Marit the homepage and the faq don't mention "typescript", can please you point it out with a specific link?

Comment: Sorry I don't use typescript/javascript myself, but there are plenty of active users & committers for the javascript version who should be able to help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated answer based on more info provided:**

The first thing you should do is separate your features and steps into their own folders

```
 tests
  features
    a.feature
    b.feature
  stepDefinitions
    aStep.ts
```

Next, create a cucumber.js file which will be the cucumber profile. I use the following profile but it's up to you what you want to do

```
    var common = [
  `--format ${
    process.env.CI || !process.stdout.isTTY ? 'progress' : 'progress-bar'
    }`,
  '--format json:./reports/cucumber-json-reports/report.json',
  '--format rerun:@rerun.txt',
  '--format usage:usage.txt',
  '--parallel 20',
  '--require ./build/tests/stepDefinitions/**/*.js',
  '--require ./build/tests/stepDefinitions/*.js',
  '--require ./build/tests/support/*.js'
].join(' ');

module.exports = {
  default: common,
};
```

The above tells cucumber where your steps are. Now you can run something like the following from the root of the project

```
tsc && ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js ./tests/features/ -p default
```

This will

1. Compile your code
2. Run the cucumber-js library
3. Run cucumber-js against the features folder
4. Run cucumber-js against the features folder with the default profile that you built in your cucumber.js file

Edit: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55378059/3323395 for how to do this without needing to compile first

Comment: Thanks, that's how the problem is solved! I was looking for the `--require` feature in cucumber, but I missed it somehow.

Comment: No problem, the documentation for cucumber-js could do with some cleaning up to help people with this. Glad I could help.

Comment: when steps are stored in a typescript file e.g. `aStep.ts`, the `this` keyword in a step refers to the typescript class. How can one use the World object of cucumber, which is accessed through `this` in .js files?

Comment: @uex That looks to be a separate question. Feel free to raise a cucumberjs question with more detail and I would be happy to review and answer.

Comment: May you live a very happy life @Ray

Answer (score 16):

You do not need to compile your code with `tsc` and then run cucumber on the compiled files, as suggested by Raymond Kelly. You can just run cucumber with the typescript transpiler using `--require-module ts-node/register`. Full example courtesy of hdorgeval at [cucumber-ts-starter](https://github.com/hdorgeval/cucumber-ts-starter)

Edit: original template mentioned was improved with new version [cucumber7-ts-starter](https://github.com/hdorgeval/cucumber7-ts-starter)

Answer (score 5):

Putting cucumber tests in src and compiling it with `tsc` is not a really good practice, because it pollutes `build` directory which is not required for the software to run, especially in production.

Instead `ts-node` can be used. Run `npm install ts-node --save-dev`. Here is an example of `cucumber-js` configuration file (all `.feature` and step definition files are in `/features` folder in my setup):

```
module.exports = {
  default: [
    '--require-module ts-node/register',
    '--require ./features/**/*.ts',
    '--require ./features/*.ts',
  ].join(' '),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your question? Cucumber has nothing to do with compiling .ts files to .js files, that is typescript doing that. If you don't want the .ts and .js files in the same folder then you can add the following to your tsconfig.json file.

```
"outDir": "typeScript"
```

This will output the javascript files to the folder "typeScript" at the root of your project. I personally like to keep them together as it can be easier to debug. There is no way to get away from the .js files being created as they are what are used when running javascript.

Comment: The problem is I want to use cucumber + typescript. If you generate the files in that directory they will not read the .feature files... So you need another step to copy over the .feature files in that temporary folder... which is dirty.

Comment: Yes, I have used cucumber and typescript without any problems. I'm not sure I follow why you need to copy folders over to run feature tests that should not be the case. 
1. Can you provide the command you are using to run your tests
2. Can you provide a sample project and I will review it and tell you the steps to follow? 

If not I can put a repository together sometime this week and show you how it works.

Comment: I don't have the code here... but you need to copy features over because you are running js files which are in the outDir which has no idea where the feature files are located.

Comment: Please check my updated question "Why just using typescript won't work:"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ts-node` module to compile your cucumber `steps.ts` file and hence you won't need to `generate.js` file

For example

```
./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js features --require step-definitions/*.ts  --require-module ts-node/register --format node_modules/cucumber-pretty"
```